# Export html area as image with html2canvas

Tags: reactjs, html2canvas

I am having a React app. I need to be able to export component as a png/jpg. I am trying to do that with html2canvas library.

I tried with this naive approach

```
const printDocument = () => {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  });
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="capture" style={{ padding: 10, background: "#f5da55" }}>
        <h4 style={{ color: "#000" }}>Hello world!</h4>
      </div>

      <button onClick={printDocument}>Print</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError
(0 , _html2canvas.html2canvas) is not a function
printDocument
/src/App.js:12:14
   9 | // };
  10 | 
  11 | const printDocument = () => {
> 12 |   html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
     |              ^
  13 |     document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  14 |   });
  15 | };
```

How can I achieve this in ReactJs?

Comment: You can use `Ref` for the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following import statement

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

You can use `useRef` hook of react

```
const printDocument = (domElement) => {
  html2canvas(domElement).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  });
};

export default function App() {

   const canvasRef = useRef()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={canvasRef} style={{ padding: 10, background: "#f5da55" }}>
        <h4 style={{ color: "#000" }}>Hello world!</h4>
      </div>

      <button onClick={()=>printDocument(canvasRef.current)}>Print</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Still getting:  (0 , _html2canvas.html2canvas) is not a function

Comment: @Nemus how are you importing html2canvas? I used `import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';` and it is working.

Comment: yes, that was the problem. I imported it with { html2canvas }

Answer (score 0):

**You will have to change only import statement of html2canvas library like this.**

`import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';`

enjoy coding.